# Third party Solution for Garbage Collection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, memory-management, garbage-collection

Is there any third party solution , VCL ,Plugins etc to do automatic garbage collection in Delphi for win32

Comment: Unfortunately, garbage collector for native Delphi is not yet in sight. That is the only thing I miss besides 64 bit compiler.

Comment: I always considered the advantages of GC overrated

Comment: hey  Marco van de Voort  if it is so  why .net  (according to my knowledge delphi has anything .net can do except GC , WPF , silverlight  )

Comment: I would advise against this anyway since anyone reading Delphi code expects the developer to "clean up" after themselves unless using interfaces. Using a GC for Delphi, even if one existed, is likely to cause more grief than benefit in a shared development environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use interfaces for doing such garbage collection.

If you use interfaces and not classes, you don't have to put an explicit try...finally block, with a call to the free method in the finally section. The compiler will generate it for you, just like with regular string methods.

You can extend this trick to every object, with code like the one published in http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28217

But this won't be a full garbage collector, like in java or DotNet. It's only reference counting.

IMHO [full garbage collector is evil](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/8/13/we-dont-need-no-stinking-garbage-collection.html). Managing memory is not difficult in Delphi. You'll type a little more, but in all cases, the performance and global memory consummation will be better with no garbage collector.

Comment: Great tip! I myself wanted to suggest this, since I already use this technique for over 6 years already.

Comment: Beware of circular references with Interfaces, that would prevent the RefCount to decrease to 0 and you would leak memory.

Comment: @François You're perfectly right, even if I'm not sure in which case it will occur. That's perhaps why I myself never use the interfaces trick on production. Extra typing of try...finally..Free..end, or proper Destroy override are proper way of handling memory. But my fear is perhaps not founded. Did you have already triggered these circular references problems?

Comment: I've also used interfaces/TInterfacedObject for many years - but you've to be careful with reference counting - it can happen that a reference will go out of scope and your ref count will drop to 0 causing a hard to track down AV or nil value.

Comment: @A.Bouchez - "IMHO full garbage collector is evil." I strongly disagree - garbage collection is the greatest thing to come along **since** Delphi. Proof: see how many posts you find here on SO related to memory management in Delphi, C++, etc. And with today's hardware, IMO your contentions about performance and global memory consumption are virtually irrelevant (ten years ago maybe they weren't), particularly compared with the benefits gained from GC. I love Delphi but it's clearly a **20th Century Language**.

Comment: @Mikey That's why Google did to add some much tricks to maintain the memory consumption low on Android AND let use Java GC. The number of posts in SO about memory management with no GC is to compare with the number of posts about performance and scaling a server using J2EE performance e.g. GC has a cost you can avoid by managing your memory, and knowing what you are doing. Linux manages its memory. Oracle does. iOS does (by reference counting like Delphi string). J2EE does not and is difficult to scale. "Evil" was an opinion. It was a bit trolling. Sorry. But I still don't like it.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: haven't worked with Java but with C# and Python, & been working with Delphi forever. I do know how to manage memory-also know with Delphi I spend a lot of time and write more code to manage memory -something I don't have to deal with in Python or C#. I do understand your POV, but are you sure those post about performance and scalability are due to GC? There are other factors besides GC that will impact performance and scalability, particularly when you're dealing with a VM, bytecode etc as opposed to native compiled exe's. Today's hardware helps plenty too, even if GC is expensive.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: "Evil" was an opinion. It was a bit trolling.": NP - a bit of hyperbole grabs attention and makes for a lively discussion.

Comment: @Mikey About GC and hardware, it's sure that the Python VM is the main performance bottleneck. Dot Net has a much better design about performance (with its JIT and internal memory structures which will avoid object creation for low-level types), and its GC has been finely tuned for most applications. With interfaces, default properties and strings, you can make some expressive tools in Delphi, too. I was impressed when I wrote my [SynProject](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=16) tool about how some Delphi structures can be used to produce Python-like expressiveness.

Comment: What a lovely discussion, over a garbage smell... ;)

Comment: @A.Bouchez - I will check out your SynProject - in fact I was just over there and saw some good stuff on the blog - right now I'm extending a big, ancient, cumbersome D5 application with D-XE and ISAPI running on Server 2008 R2 - have been looking for ways to leverage the 64 bit OS and drivers. I hope they do a good job on the 64 bit compiler and get it out quickly (it's long overdue...)- it will give Delphi a much needed boost. Regardless, certainly you can do many things with Delphi, but work and time are costly. I'd rather learn and use a 21st century style language than retrofit Delphi.

Comment: @A.Bouchez -"it's sure that the Python VM is the main performance bottleneck." - built-in Python modules call C libs - a thin wrapper on the C libs. When it comes to extensions and home grown code, that's where you have to watch out, and of course you need to write with scalability in mind no matter what platform you use - you can bog down even the best hardware with garbage code. But I don't think the problem is GC per se. Ah - the sweet, poignant smell of garbage...

Answer (score 3):

There is [API for Boehm Garbage Collector](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/21646) for Delphi. But it will work only on Delphi <=7 and without FastMM.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 'first party solution' that I used to use all the time, until I opted for interfaces: 
When you create a class (or sometimes a whole application), first thing you do is create a TObjectList - then every time you call a constructor, you immediately add a reference to your new instance to your TobjectList. In your destructor just make sure to free your TObjectList instance and you're good: by default TOBjectList owns every object it contains - so when you free your TObjectList, everything else will get cleaned up along with it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use FastMM or MemCheck to see where you forgot to free the memory, but at my knowledge a garbage collector full integrated in delphi for win32 does not exists.

best regards,
Radu

Comment: i dont think fastmm as a GC but a MM

Comment: yes indeed. but if there is not automated system, I believe that a system/mechanism which show you were the problems are, without taking 'by the hand' all the code from the project is a step forward.